# Rolling dice probability by solving inequlity

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I was trying to solve a problem where I have to find the probability of the sum of $\mathcal 3$ rolls of a die being less than or equal to $\mathcal 9$.
In order to solve the problem I try first to find the number of non-negative integer solutions to the following inequality:  $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} \le 6$
From this it follows that by introducing the slack variable $x_{4}$ , I could rewrite the inequality as the following equation:  $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} = 6$  where  $x_{4} = 6 - (x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3})$
Therefore the answer would be $\binom{9}{3}$ solutions, where I have to remove 4 impossible solutions leaving me with $\frac{80}{6^3}$ as the probability.
I was wondering however, if the introduction of the slack variable $x_{4}$(forcing the equation to look like as if there were $\mathcal 4$ rolls of a die instead of $\mathcal 3$), could eventually result in a wrong probability?  Is this method a reliable way for computing this probability?

Comment: BTW, it's either "dice" or "a die" (the latter seems more appropriate in your case).

Comment: @barakmanos, Thank you for the correction!

Comment: I don't understand why there are 4 impossible solutions. I can see that the dice can't be more then 6, but that only accounts for 3 impossible solutions.

Comment: @ZurLuria, Imagine the first inequality as x1 + x2 + x3 <= 9 where (1 <= x1,x2,x3 <= 6).  Now in order to have the number of non-negative integer solutions, we will have to do the following: y1 + y2 + y3 <= 6 where (0 <= y1,y2,y3 <= 5).  Therefore we will inevitably end up with 4 possible situations where 2 dice could be 1 and the 3rd being 7 and therefor impossible.

Comment: But that's 3 situations since there are 3 dice, not 4.

Comment: @ZurLuria, Correct me if I am wrong as this is exactly why I am seeking help. By transforming the inequality to the following equation: y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 = 6 where y4 = 6 - ( y1 + y2 + y3 ), it seems to me that the 3 rolls of a die is now 4 rolls of a die and therefor 4 impossible solutions ensue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct, except that you count 4 illegal solutions instead of 3.

As Barak Manos says, the probability of the event that the sum of the dice is at most 9 is the number of dice rolls in which the sum is at most 9 divided by 216, the total number of rolls.

It remains to count the number of solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3 \leq 9$ for integers between 1 and 6. This is now strictly a counting problem - it has nothing to do with probability or dice anymore. Barak Manos solves it by going over all possible solutions, but this would be impractical for a large number of dice - your proposed solution is better I think.

As you explain, the number of solutions is equal to the number of nonnegative integer solutions to $ y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 = 6$ where $0 \leq y_1,y_2,y_3 \leq 5$ and $y_4 \geq 0$. The first three $y$'s correspond to the first three $x$'s minus 1, which is why they are at most $5$. The slack variable $y_4$ has no such constraint. Now by the stars and bars method the number of solutions is $\binom{9}{3}$, minus the ***3*** illegal solutions in which one of the three $x_i$'s is 7. This gives 81 solutions, which yields the same probability that Barak Manos got.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong as this is exactly why I am seeking help. By transforming the inequality to the following equation: y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 = 6 where y4 = 6 - ( y1 + y2 + y3 ), it seems to me that the 3 rolls of a die is now 4 rolls of a die and therefor 4 impossible solutions ensue.

Comment: I edited my answer a bit to clear this up. Basically the fourth variable is a slack variable and doesn't correspond to a die, so it doesn't have to be at most 5. When y4=6 you get the solution y1=y2=y3=0 which corresponds to the legal dice roll (1,1,1).

Answer (score 0):

**An alternative solution (not a direct answer to your question):**

Sums equal to $3$:

- We have $1$ permutation  of $1,1,1$

Sums equal to $4$:

- We have $3$ permutations of $1,1,2$

Sums equal to $5$:

- We have $3$ permutations of $1,1,3$
- We have $3$ permutations of $1,2,2$

Sums equal to $6$:

- We have $3$ permutations of $1,1,4$
- We have $6$ permutations of $1,2,3$
- We have $1$ permutation  of $2,2,2$

Sums equal to $7$:

- We have $3$ permutations of $1,1,5$
- We have $6$ permutations of $1,2,4$
- We have $3$ permutations of $1,3,3$
- We have $3$ permutations of $2,2,3$

Sums equal to $8$:

- We have $3$ permutations of $1,1,6$
- We have $6$ permutations of $1,2,5$
- We have $6$ permutations of $1,3,4$
- We have $3$ permutations of $2,2,4$
- We have $3$ permutations of $2,3,3$

Sums equal to $9$:

- We have $6$ permutations of $1,2,6$
- We have $6$ permutations of $1,3,5$
- We have $3$ permutations of $1,4,4$
- We have $3$ permutations of $2,2,5$
- We have $6$ permutations of $2,3,4$
- We have $1$ permutation  of $3,3,3$

So the number of sums less than or equal to $9$ is $81$.

The total number of sums is $6^3=216$, hence the probability is $\frac{81}{216}$.

Comment: I think these are just the sums that are equal to 9.

Comment: @ZurLuria: You're absolutely right, thank you! I've edited.

Comment: Now your solution is correct, but it's cumbersome and hard to generalize. O. A.'s solution is better.

Comment: @ZurLuria: I agree, that's why I noted that it's an alternative solution and not a direct answer to the question at hand.